# Use Parameter in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want create a function in factory. But I don't understand how pass my parameters.

How I can set a dynamic parameter in parameter q?

```js
app.factory('Item', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource(ApiUrl('items/:id'), {}, {
            get:    { cache: false },
            getWithName: { params: {q: 'tshirt'}, isArray: true, cache: false },
            query: { isArray: true, cache: true }
        });
    }
]);

// Code Sample
$scope.items = Item.getWithName(q:$route.current.params.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.items = Item.getWithName({q:$route.current.params.name});
```